# View and delete individual messages directly from POP server in OS X Mail

Tags: mail.app, messages, macos, pop

There is/was a feature in OS X Mail that allowed to fetch the list of messages from the server in a configured POP account. This fetched only message headers - all at once - and displayed the list in a window then allowed to individually select messages and delete them directly from the server. Not all messages via the Preferences - Accounts - Advanced - Remove now option but individually.

I can't seem to find this option any more. Was this removed from Mail or just well hidden?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If accounts are inside a global Inbox, open the Inbox reveal arrow
- Right Click the individual account Inbox > Get Account Info

  [image]
- Select the Messages on Server tab
- Wait for it to load, then you can select & delete any/all messages on the server

[image]